# Nothing rendering on Windows server

Tags: templates, windows

Not sure what happens but a site I'm running on a windows server displays nothing now. I can't get it into debug mode. Also, works perfectly fine locally on MAMP and on a linux set up with 1and1... any help would be amazing!

Comment: what happens if you set the debug to 1 in index.php ? I vowed never to use 1and1 again for EE hosting, let alone on a Windows server. Did you run the EE wizard before hand to make sure the server was compatible?

Comment: It's actually on gearhost and the ee wizard passes except for supporting url segments. The sight was working fine up until I pushed a round of changes yesterday night. Setting debug to 1 doesn't give me any data for some reason.

Comment: can't say I've heard of them to be honest. What changes did you make for it to stop working?

Comment: "Site was working fine up until I pushed a round of changes yesterday night" is a huge clue but your question contains no detail about the changes. With so few details in your question, it's pretty difficult to help.

Answer (score 1):

According to Gearhost [docs](https://support.gearhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/200342625-php-ini-settings), you can set a PHP.INI file per site. Using these docs, you can override the default PHP.INI settings. Create a file which shows the output of the phpinfo function to see what your current settings are. It's possible that PHP is set to output errors to a log file and not to display them on screen. This makes sense for a production site.